# Visual Studio Code not reading modules in python3

Tags: python, module, compiler-errors, biopython

Sorry if this has been asked a thousand times, haven't found a solution that worked or that I understand. I'm very new to this, and just install Biopython through homebrew (mac) and confirmed that it WILL work in the visual studio terminal, but gives this error in the actual program:

```
# my code
from Bio.Seq import Seq

seq1 = Seq("CCCGGAGAGA")
print(type(seq1))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/justinbeutel/Desktop/Python Programs 2020/BioPython_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Bio.Seq import Seq
ImportError: No module named Bio.Seq
```

I can see on the bottom of my screen that I'm running 3.7.4 64-bit, so that's not the problem. I've also noticed that I can't use the built in module statistics for some reason either, but that's whatever. If anyone happens to know how to fix this, could you please go step-by-step on the solution (good enough for someone with literally no visual studio experience)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not install it correctly.

Please install it again or upgrade : [Documentation](https://biopython.org/wiki/Getting_Started)

Similar issue someone posted in Github, I hope this will help you.
[ImportError: No module named Bio](https://github.com/nh2tran/DeepNovo/issues/5)